# How to use Plupload HTML4 upload for S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, plupload, html4

I'm trying to get an html4 runtime of Plupload to work with S3. Unfortunately the [example I found here](http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=133) must be a really old version of plupload or not properly documented, and has no live working example or source code download.

So I took my working version of Plupload/Flash runtime to S3 and simply put html4 runtime instead of flash and added `'success_action_redirect':` *(I learned from plupload forums that this is needed for plupload to know when the file upload is complete)*. I came to find out that it actually works, but some of the script does fail.

Here is my source code...

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$bucket = 'MyBucket';
$accessKeyId = 'MyKey';
$secret = 'MySecret';

// Policy Setup
if (!function_exists('hash_hmac')) : function hash_hmac($algo, $data, $key, $raw_output = false){
    $blocksize = 64;
    if (strlen($key) > $blocksize)
        $key = pack('H*', $algo($key));

    $key = str_pad($key, $blocksize, chr(0x00));
    $ipad = str_repeat(chr(0x36), $blocksize);
    $opad = str_repeat(chr(0x5c), $blocksize);
    $hmac = pack('H*', $algo(($key^$opad) . pack('H*', $algo(($key^$ipad) . $data))));

    return $raw_output ? $hmac : bin2hex($hmac);
}
endif;
// prepare policy
$policy = base64_encode(json_encode(array(
    'expiration' => date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z', strtotime('+1 day')),  
    'conditions' => array(
        array('bucket' => $bucket),
        array('acl' => 'authenticated-read'),
        array('success_action_redirect' => 'http://mydomain.com/ThisCanBeAnyPage.php'),
        array('starts-with', '$key', ''),
        array('success_action_status' => '201'),
        array('starts-with', '$name', ''),  
        array('starts-with', '$Filename', ''), 
    )
)));
// Sign Policy
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $policy, $secret, true));
?>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plupload.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plupload.html4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Custom example logic
$(function() {
    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        preinit : {
            UploadFile: function(up, file) {
        // When file is loaded, directory on S3 is set here.
                up.settings.multipart_params.key = 'myFolder/'+file.name;
            }
        },
        runtimes : 'html4',
        browse_button : 'pickfiles',
        container : 'container',
        url : 'http://<?php echo $bucket; ?>.s3.amazonaws.com/',
        max_file_size : '300mb',
        multipart: true,
        multipart_params: {
            'key': '${filename}', // use filename as a key
            'success_action_redirect':'http://mydomain.com/ThisCanBeAnyPage.php',
            'Filename': '${filename}', // adding this to keep consistency across the runtimes
            'acl': 'authenticated-read',
            'success_action_status': '201',
            'AWSAccessKeyId' : '<?php echo $accessKeyId; ?>',       
            'policy': '<?php echo $policy; ?>',
            'signature': '<?php echo $signature; ?>'
        },
        file_data_name: 'file',
        multiple_queues: true,
        filters : [
            {title : "Image Files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg"},
        ],
        flash_swf_url : 'js/plupload.flash.swf',
        silverlight_xap_url : 'js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
    });

    uploader.bind('Init', function(up, params) {
        //$('#filelist').html("<div>Current runtime: " + params.runtime + "</div>");
    });

    $('#uploadfiles').click(function(e) {
        uploader.start();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
        $.each(files, function(i, file) {
        // file.name seems to be the only thing that is returned so file.size is displayed as 'N/A'
            $('#filelist').append(
                '<div class="Section" id="'+file.id+'">'
                    +file.name+' ('+plupload.formatSize(file.size)+')&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>'
                    +'</b><div class="PlupLoadingBarWrap"><div class="PlupLoadingBar"></div></div>'
                +'</div>'
            );
        });
        up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
    });

    uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
        // file.name seems to be the only thing that is returned
        // This triggers when file is complete before 'FileUploaded' and not during upload process.
    });

    uploader.bind('Error', function(up, err) {
        // Haven't received an error to know if this works.
        $('#filelist').append("<div>Error: " + err.code +
            ", Message: " + err.message +
            (err.file ? ", File: " + err.file.name : "") +
            "</div>"
        );

        up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
    });

    uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file) {
        // file.name seems to be the only thing that is returned
        // This does trigger once file is completely loaded
    });

    uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function(up, files){
        // Calls a function
    });

    uploader.init();
});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<h3>Custom example</h3>
<div id="container">
    <div id="filelist">No runtime found.</div>
    <br />
    <a id="pickfiles" href="#">[Select files]</a>
    <a id="uploadfiles" href="#">[Upload files]</a>
</div>
```

So to conclude, this script does work but lacks file.size and there is no progress indication according to what I was able to find out. I want to knowt if there is a plupload html4 script out there that includes the things that are missing here. I have a workaround in mind that I have yet to test. But I'll keep this updated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is NO.

HTML4 in itself does not support any of those functions.

But you can do it if you play around with the submit feature. Basically you will need to engineer your own chunking on the client, submit the chunk using post and control the number of chunks to make a progress bar. Its simple in theory but ugly in practise.  Why can you use the flash  or silverlight injection?